# Windows Firewall on GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy

I am trying to trouble shoot a Windows Firewall on my Domain. Following services are allowed through the firewall

- DNS
- Active Directory
- File and Printer Sharing
- Network Discovery
- Remote Desktop
- Remote Event Long Management
- Remote Server Management

Upon restart and GP Update for my GPO the firewall is enabled but it will not show any network discovery. I on my local client and the DC they firewall is on and the allowed ports are checked.

Also another side problem is with the Firewall on it takes a long time for users to login to machines. DNS is fine. It is on the correct.

Can anyone suggest something I am missing?

Running windows Server 2008 R2 with Windows 7 Clients.

Thanks.

UPDATE 1: Turned firewall on and here is what happens. Machine logs in but takes about 5 minutes to log. Network discovery does not work. File sharing does work but makes it VERY VERY slow (i.e. you can resolve the computer by going to Start > Run > Computer Name). DNS IS WORKING. Why would the firewall slow everything down to a snails pace even with all the allowed ports through the firewall?

Comment: I'm not following. What's the problem?

Comment: @joeqwerty When the firewall is on the computers cannot use network discovery mean when you go to Explorer and click on Network nothing comes up. And now the gpupdate /force is not finding the GP to update with the firewall on.  Which is even more confusing.

Comment: Is your switch/gateway configured to drop those packets?  Is there a device on the network that does packet inspection?

Comment: @Colyn1337 no there isn't. When the firewall is off File Sharing and Network discovery works fine. With the firewall on it takes forever to get to shares but Discovery doesn't show anything.

Comment: Do you allow alll outgoing traffic? If not, try that.Maybe turning on firewall logging on dropped packets should give you the proper info.